# SpriteKit: Move Object on Rope along a Track / Conveyor Belt

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I have a sprite hanging from a rope in SpriteKit.  I have the rope pinned to an object I'd like to slide back and fourth (to simulate the rope being attached to a track or conveyor belt).  Imagine clothes hanging on the revolving rack of a dry cleaners store.  Similar to that!

Anyway, I can't figure out the proper way to move my rope as if it its connected to the track.

Pinning the rope to another (track) object and moving that track object doesn't seem to work.  I can't apply move actions to a sprite that has physics (without the simulation getting all messed up).

I've also tried adjusting the track objects velocity directly to (2,0) in the update method (Including all the other update callbacks SpriteKit surfaces).  The only problem is the weight of the rope and attached object eventually pull the track object down. I think this happens because didSimulatePhysics happens no matter what.

Any suggestions on how to move my sprite on a rope along a track?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possibly `SKPhysicsJoint` or `SKPhysicsJointSliding`
https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skphysicsjoint
https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skphysicsjointsliding